# Can't get correct page by using "service nginx start " but ok by using "nginx"

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

> Os: CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611
>  nginx: 1.2.1 (installed by
>   yum)
>  php: php7.0.1

I use `service nginx start` to start nginx, I got *403 forbidden*

But when I use `nginx`, I get the correct page.

I've tried to change "nginx.conf",`user nginx` to `user root`, then I can't use `service nginx start` anymore (the same as service nginx restart/stop)

I have tried to change dir's group and user but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollback your changes in nginx.conf and then check SELinux status by `sestatus` or `getenforce`  command. If it returns enforcing set SELinux to permissive mode by `setenforce 0` command and check nginx.

If it not works set your nginx root directory permission as follow :

chown nginx:nginx /path/to/nginx/root/directory
chmod 755 /path/to/nginx/root/directory

Comment: Thank you so much~ it works. But when i reboot  the system，i need to set SELinux to permissive mode by setenforce 0 again.So i modified   SeLinux'config SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled.But i want to ask Will this setting reduce the system secriuty?

Comment: Your welcome. Set SELINUX=permissive and reboot again. In permissive mode Linux logs some audit files. Audit files used to create SELinux policy.
Read more about SELinux and policy 
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/rhlcommon-chapter-0001.html